# Moving a div child from one parent to another after div selection and parent selection using event propagation

Tags: javascript

I'm building out the game Towers of Hanoi, i've got everything figured out except for how to move a div (my disk) from one parent(the rods) to another in the following sequence: click on disk(div/child node) to select, then click on rod(parent node) that you want the disk to move to.

I've tried using multiple event handlers within one another in order to solve the problem, as well as using removeEventHandler after the div has been moved to a new parent node. I've also tried stopPropogation to prevent bubbling, but neither have worked out for me.

```
// Moving the blocks from one container to the other
// use 'prepend' in order to insert new disk at the top of the parent node as the first child


function move() {
  for (let i = 0; i < disks.length; i++)
    disks[i].addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      // activeDisk = evt.target.dataset.value

      // give red border on block when selected
      disks[i].style.border = 'Red 2px Solid';
      console.log(disks[i])

      // after  disk is selected, click on desired stack to move disk to
      stackA.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        stackA.prepend(disks[i])
        win(evt)
        })
      stackA.removeEventListener('click', function(){
        return console.log(stopped)
      })

      stackB.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        stackB.prepend(disks[i])
        win(evt)
      })
      stackB.removeEventListener('click', function(){
        return console.log(stopped)
      })
      stackC.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        stackC.prepend(disks[i])
        win(evt)
        })
        stackC.removeEventListener('click', function(){
          return console.log(stopped)
        })
        check(evt)
      })
      }
```

I'd like for my disks to move to the containers and then deselect in order to move them individually. I'm able to move them but when i select them and then try to deselect them to move a different disk independently it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't removeEventListener like this, it will not work.
You have to create a listener function and use that to add or remove later.

```
function exampleFunction(){ // your logic here }
stackA.addEventListener("click", exampleFunction);
stackA.removeEventListener("click", exampleFunction);
```